# finding item in two lists efficiently Python

Tags: python

I have a working function to allow me to search two lists and see if the items in list1 are present in list2, if an item is not present in list2 from list1 then I would like that output to another list. However this takes AGES to run and I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this.

```
def compare(list1,list2):
    x=[]
    for i in list1:
        if i not in list2:
            x.append(i)

    return x
```

Comment: Restating the goal to make sure I have it clear: the end result of this function is a list containing only the elements of `list1` that do not appear in `list2`?

Comment: If so, `[x for x in list1 if x not in list2]` seems like a reasonably fast and straightforward alternative.

Comment: Yes in a faster way than I have already

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to what I have already?

Comment: Do you need to preserve order? If not, `list(set(list1) - set(list2))`

Comment: @DanielPrinsloo In output, I suppose. It's probably better optimized and a little more efficient. What's the size of the lists you're trying to process?

Comment: The lists are very large hundreds of thousands and the output is only a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sets.

Example:

```
>>> list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list2 = ['c', 'd', 'e']
>>> set(list1) - set(list2)
{'b', 'a'}
```

Sets by default do not preserve order. If order is important for you, check the recipe for [`OrderedSet`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694-orderedset/).

Comment: order is not important thank you I would like to accept both your answers but cannot unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

Since you're only checking for inclusion in `list2`, make that one a set:

```
def compare(list1, list2):
    s2 = set(list2)
    result = [i  for i in list1  if i not in s2] # simple list comprehension
    return result
```

This preserves the input order and semantics of your program, while being significantly faster: set inclusion testing is O(1), while list inclusion testing is O(n), bringing your whole algorithm from O(n^2) down to O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Can you use sets?

It would be like:

`print list(set(list1)-set(list2))`

But it will remove duplicates.

Comment: Removing duplicates would be great

Comment: Are we sure this is faster than, say, a list comprehension? `set` has to consume both lists whole to add them, right? Then you convert back to a list at the end (without the original ordering). I'd like to see some `timeit` results.

Comment: Ill have a look at the different results and edit my answer

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist for large lists, it will certainly be much faster. The set algorithm runtime is O(n1 + n2) (the cost of hashing each member of n1 and n2), but the list comprehension runtime will be O(n1 * n2) (the cost of finding each member of n1 in n2, where the worst case is n1 not in n2.)

Comment: Is there a way to preserve duplicates using sets? (just out of curiosity)

Comment: @DanielPrinsloo with sets - no

Comment: And not using sets??

Comment: Cause the issue is currently I'm using this on 4 files and checking each file against the other 3 using this to determine what is missing from the other files that is in this file. However when I check it will only return the missing item is in one file when I check however it is in two

Comment: @DanielPrinsloo It's best to ask one more question and describe what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The `set1 - set2` answers are correct iff you don't mind losing order and duplicates. But even if you *do*, using sets can vastly increase the efficiency and readability of the program if `list2` is large:

```
set2 = set(list2)
result = [item for item in list1 if item not in set2]
```

The cost of generating the set is `O(len(list2))`. So the runtime of this approach will be `O(len(list2) + len(list1))` and makes a lot of sense unless list2 is very small.